# How can I create Visual effect to alert view similar to iOS default alerts?

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertcontroller, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I have created `UIVisualEffectView` and I like it much. But, I don't have any idea on how can I create iOS like alert view having blur effect.

Here is the screenshot which explains what I need.

[image]

Comment: You need to use [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uivisualeffectview)

Comment: It just explains how to create `uivisualeffectview`.

Comment: you want to add the blur effect to  UIalertCONTROLLER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample it may be help you 
you can change BlurEffect type

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *backgroundView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```